# factor to numeric: data are totally different

Tags: r

When I want to change a column from factor to numeric with "as.numeric()", the final numbers are totally different from what I imported.

It is a problem due to the comma? Really strange...

Thanks!

> dput(datatest)
>   structure(list(HOURS.at.sea = structure(c(261L, 84L, 83L, 260L, 
>   307L, 292L, 252L, 72L, 59L, 343L, 244L, 78L, 56L, 256L, 9L, 269L, 
>   291L, 254L, 69L, 65L, 267L, 283L, 1L, 80L, 169L, 1L, 115L, 67L, 
>   75L, 3L, 309L, 59L, 33L, 52L, 75L, 37L, 51L, 75L, 22L, 2L, 49L, 
>   83L, 21L, 2L, 53L, 70L, 19L, 3L, 57L, 70L, 22L, 3L, 58L, 78L, 
>   36L, 49L, 2L, 66L, 115L, 52L, 72L, 114L, 57L, 78L, 116L, 56L, 
>   68L, 116L, 55L, 70L, 327L, 6L, 257L, 2L, 107L, 176L, 182L, 4L, 
>   114L, 35L, 46L, 3L, 67L, 34L, 46L, 3L, 79L, 40L, 50L, 69L, 38L, 
>   52L, 2L, 69L, 38L, 85L, 49L, 70L, 64L, 70L, 3L, 1L, 206L, 231L, 
>   58L, 55L, 109L, 212L, 220L, 53L, 56L, 125L, 3L, 5L, 214L, 231L, 
>   57L, 55L, 107L, 217L, 228L, 52L, 57L, 105L, 210L, 231L, 56L, 
>   55L, 105L, 215L, 232L, 55L, 54L, 90L, 210L, 230L, 58L, 54L, 108L, 
>   218L, 228L, 57L, 56L, 96L, 213L, 228L, 55L, 57L, 106L, 217L, 
>   232L, 58L, 73L, 110L, 217L, 233L, 57L, 59L, 117L, 7L, 222L, 233L, 
>   59L, 56L, 107L, 219L, 231L, 57L, 56L, 109L, 221L, 233L, 56L, 
>   57L, 106L, 1L, 1L, 247L, 317L, 159L, 316L, 229L, 306L, 129L, 
>   120L, 29L, 74L, 287L, 12L, 151L, 109L, 68L, 125L, 270L, 1L, 56L, 
>   224L, 180L, 76L, 281L, 86L, 79L, 258L, 83L, 1L, 229L, 23L, 132L, 
>   56L, 59L, 76L, 115L, 110L, 28L, 235L, 226L, 16L, 134L, 55L, 57L, 
>   66L, 124L, 117L, 28L, 240L, 1L, 52L, 335L, 32L, 59L, 186L, 71L, 
>   4L, 7L, 5L, 39L, 59L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 293L, 4L, 66L, 99L, 110L, 54L, 
>   2L, 4L, 148L, 221L, 322L, 31L, 170L, 1L, 286L, 162L, 336L, 129L, 
>   138L, 70L, 71L, 125L, 241L, 277L, 6L, 8L, 76L, 84L, 320L, 339L, 
>   117L, 137L, 69L, 80L, 1L, 243L, 92L, 139L, 149L, 54L, 67L, 262L, 
>   1L, 240L, 78L, 73L, 1L, 187L, 48L, 65L, 97L, 263L, 332L, 187L, 
>   103L, 29L, 79L, 266L, 334L, 188L, 303L, 96L, 264L, 313L, 184L, 
>   45L, 66L, 105L, 263L, 330L, 184L, 53L, 24L, 96L, 97L, 272L, 331L, 
>   185L, 47L, 68L, 102L, 265L, 342L, 187L, 97L, 49L, 58L, 264L, 
>   333L, 195L, 96L, 31L, 181L, 265L, 1L, 236L, 79L, 270L, 89L, 246L, 
>   45L, 207L, 166L, 79L, 41L, 177L, 55L, 128L, 1L, 152L, 205L, 57L, 
>   168L, 195L, 284L, 94L, 118L, 340L, 82L, 123L, 57L, 73L, 118L, 
>   58L, 227L, 18L, 51L, 323L, 178L, 49L, 120L, 26L, 59L, 52L, 67L, 
>   67L, 114L, 234L, 1L, 15L, 201L, 163L, 42L, 72L, 47L, 10L, 66L, 
>   106L, 224L, 17L, 189L, 44L, 200L, 164L, 45L, 69L, 47L, 67L, 102L, 
>   275L, 14L, 190L, 30L, 199L, 161L, 47L, 71L, 52L, 276L, 32L, 199L, 
>   161L, 48L, 73L, 46L, 70L, 103L, 273L, 23L, 271L, 47L, 74L, 46L, 
>   57L, 308L, 23L, 1L, 66L, 338L, 242L, 155L, 72L, 249L, 57L, 80L, 
>   94L, 225L, 341L, 104L, 1L, 116L, 44L, 5L, 90L, 293L, 50L, 238L, 
>   84L, 46L, 216L, 46L, 278L, 325L, 57L, 314L, 48L, 108L, 44L, 50L, 
>   59L, 1L, 289L, 49L, 42L, 295L, 53L, 304L, 3L, 49L, 59L, 1L, 74L, 
>   15L, 84L, 26L, 244L, 129L, 80L, 82L, 158L, 126L, 45L, 79L, 65L, 
>   344L, 258L, 106L, 81L, 75L, 95L, 4L, 144L, 140L, 25L, 83L, 76L, 
>   1L, 209L, 99L, 42L, 79L, 312L, 1L, 27L, 238L, 76L, 70L, 119L, 
>   115L, 69L, 305L, 1L, 318L, 139L, 187L, 84L, 67L, 150L, 44L, 131L, 
>   73L, 172L, 123L, 57L, 73L, 251L, 1L, 122L, 254L, 28L, 5L, 4L, 
>   4L, 4L, 6L, 156L, 247L, 88L, 248L, 81L, 78L, 42L, 258L, 87L, 
>   165L, 50L, 173L, 80L, 98L, 41L, 72L, 108L, 102L, 48L, 74L, 102L, 
>   223L, 103L, 48L, 5L, 5L, 67L, 98L, 226L, 104L, 57L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
>   2L, 72L, 98L, 228L, 105L, 48L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 78L, 94L, 234L, 
>   103L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 60L, 98L, 84L, 218L, 11L, 
>   45L, 1L, 158L, 175L, 95L, 4L, 65L, 112L, 311L, 216L, 146L, 1L, 
>   131L, 217L, 55L, 302L, 60L, 202L, 66L, 56L, 167L, 79L, 179L, 
>   142L, 2L, 54L, 145L, 1L, 196L, 60L, 70L, 118L, 23L, 91L, 42L, 
>   197L, 50L, 67L, 77L, 83L, 44L, 66L, 140L, 44L, 83L, 337L, 1L, 
>   52L, 319L, 1L, 47L, 62L, 50L, 234L, 81L, 57L, 254L, 56L, 61L, 
>   45L, 232L, 80L, 57L, 253L, 121L, 234L, 77L, 51L, 241L, 49L, 63L, 
>   44L, 234L, 81L, 54L, 250L, 2L, 1L, 153L, 338L, 107L, 141L, 68L, 
>   55L, 128L, 225L, 100L, 171L, 193L, 194L, 160L, 338L, 112L, 139L, 
>   3L, 68L, 2L, 65L, 130L, 49L, 139L, 1L, 50L, 310L, 76L, 279L, 
>   141L, 1L, 1L, 74L, 251L, 204L, 1L, 217L, 84L, 198L, 43L, 54L, 
>   298L, 268L, 26L, 208L, 49L, 51L, 297L, 226L, 92L, 199L, 42L, 
>   54L, 299L, 267L, 26L, 199L, 31L, 58L, 298L, 218L, 96L, 203L, 
>   43L, 58L, 299L, 267L, 288L, 25L, 183L, 42L, 315L, 92L, 199L, 
>   32L, 56L, 300L, 1L, 105L, 103L, 96L, 90L, 76L, 248L, 290L, 294L, 
>   274L, 94L, 56L, 133L, 136L, 72L, 67L, 67L, 115L, 244L, 174L, 
>   112L, 84L, 68L, 143L, 240L, 1L, 220L, 147L, 209L, 117L, 157L, 
>   321L, 113L, 138L, 13L, 154L, 118L, 139L, 111L, 55L, 1L, 102L, 
>   51L, 80L, 208L, 241L, 70L, 96L, 80L, 259L, 103L, 70L, 223L, 326L, 
>   57L, 285L, 53L, 324L, 67L, 255L, 105L, 221L, 105L, 76L, 53L, 
>   54L, 83L, 84L, 247L, 91L, 68L, 106L, 30L, 324L, 59L, 65L, 296L, 
>   79L, 20L, 79L, 301L, 52L, 70L, 1L, 135L, 245L, 53L, 217L, 247L, 
>   83L, 75L, 2L, 78L, 242L, 192L, 249L, 56L, 77L, 99L, 82L, 75L, 
>   65L, 241L, 6L, 63L, 112L, 82L, 80L, 49L, 239L, 191L, 101L, 1L, 
>   14L, 222L, 71L, 74L, 98L, 215L, 325L, 282L, 117L, 325L, 226L, 
>   97L, 91L, 92L, 57L, 72L, 246L, 1L, 211L, 53L, 70L, 131L, 239L, 
>   237L, 217L, 53L, 70L, 93L, 242L, 329L, 43L, 92L, 104L, 127L, 
>   50L, 306L, 328L, 256L, 76L, 49L, 280L, 1L, 201L, 103L, 73L, 4L, 
>   4L, 4L, 242L, 125L), .Label = c("#VALUE!", "0,1", "0,2", "0,3", 
>   "0,4", "0,5", "0,6", "0,8", "1,0", "1,3", "10,1", "10,2", "10,3", 
>   "10,4", "10,5", "10,8", "10,9", "1023,7", "107,5", "108,5", "108,9", 
>   "109,2", "11,0", "11,1", "11,2", "11,3", "11,4", "11,5", "11,6", 
>   "11,7", "11,8", "11,9", "110,1", "110,2", "110,4", "110,7", "110,8", 
>   "110,9", "111,1", "115,8", "12,0", "12,1", "12,2", "12,3", "12,4", 
>   "12,5", "12,6", "12,7", "12,8", "12,9", "13,0", "13,1", "13,2", 
>   "13,3", "13,4", "13,5", "13,6", "13,7", "13,8", "13,9", "132,9", 
>   "133,8", "133,9", "138,1", "14,0", "14,1", "14,2", "14,3", "14,4", 
>   "14,5", "14,6", "14,7", "14,8", "14,9", "15,0", "15,1", "15,2", 
>   "15,3", "15,4", "15,5", "15,6", "15,7", "15,8", "15,9", "156,1", 
>   "1569,2", "157,3", "157,6", "158,5", "16,0", "16,1", "16,2", 
>   "16,3", "16,4", "16,5", "16,6", "16,7", "16,8", "16,9", "162,4", 
>   "165,6", "17,0", "17,1", "17,2", "17,3", "17,4", "17,5", "17,6", 
>   "17,7", "17,8", "17,9", "18,0", "18,2", "18,3", "18,4", "18,5", 
>   "18,6", "18,7", "18,8", "18,9", "180,9", "181,4", "19,0", "19,1", 
>   "19,3", "19,4", "19,5", "19,6", "19,7", "19,8", "19,9", "2,1", 
>   "2,3", "2,5", "2,7", "2,8", "20,0", "20,1", "20,3", "20,5", "20,7", 
>   "208,1", "21,0", "21,1", "21,3", "21,5", "21,6", "21,8", "2101,8", 
>   "22,0", "22,1", "22,4", "22,5", "22,6", "225,8", "23,1", "23,2", 
>   "23,3", "23,6", "23,9", "24,3", "24,9", "25,3", "25,4", "253,7", 
>   "254,9", "255,3", "26,9", "27,7", "277,6", "278,9", "279,3", 
>   "28,0", "288,3", "29,6", "297,3", "299,6", "3,2", "3,3", "3,8", 
>   "30,3", "303,8", "32,1", "32,4", "32,5", "32,6", "32,7", "32,9", 
>   "322,0", "322,2", "326,4", "326,7", "328,9", "329,4", "33,1", 
>   "33,2", "33,3", "33,4", "33,5", "33,6", "33,7", "33,8", "33,9", 
>   "331,4", "34,0", "34,4", "34,5", "34,7", "34,9", "35,0", "35,3", 
>   "35,5", "35,6", "35,7", "35,8", "35,9", "36,0", "36,1", "36,2", 
>   "36,3", "36,4", "36,5", "36,6", "36,7", "36,8", "36,9", "37,0", 
>   "37,1", "37,2", "37,3", "37,4", "37,5", "37,6", "37,8", "37,9", 
>   "370,8", "375,6", "38,0", "38,1", "38,2", "38,3", "38,4", "38,5", 
>   "38,6", "38,7", "38,8", "38,9", "39,0", "39,1", "39,2", "39,3", 
>   "39,4", "39,6", "39,7", "39,8", "39,9", "396,2", "40,1", "40,2", 
>   "40,3", "40,7", "40,9", "41,3", "41,4", "41,6", "41,7", "41,8", 
>   "41,9", "42,7", "42,8", "421,0", "43,5", "43,7", "433,0", "44,2", 
>   "446,1", "448,9", "449,3", "45,4", "45,8", "47,7", "472,8", "49,2", 
>   "492,3", "494,9", "497,9", "507,6", "520,8", "54,4", "541,6", 
>   "575,4", "577,4", "6,6", "6,8", "60,0", "61,2", "61,4", "61,5", 
>   "61,6", "61,7", "61,9", "619,1", "62,3", "62,9", "63,0", "63,5", 
>   "64,0", "64,1", "64,6", "642,8", "646,2", "65,8", "663,5", "666,2", 
>   "671,6", "7,2", "7,8", "708,7", "711,6", "8,1", "8,2", "8,3", 
>   "8,5", "8,7", "8,8", "8,9", "804,0", "829,0", "856,0", "87,0", 
>   "87,4", "87,5", "88,1", "88,3", "9,0", "9,1", "9,3", "9,5", "9,7", 
>   "9,8", "9,9", "90,9", "928,2", "975,8"), class = "factor")), .Names = "HOURS.at.sea", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -913L))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66565/discussion-on-question-by-nif-factor-to-numeric-data-are-totally-different).

Answer (score 8):

If the commas are thousands separators, a common problem when users save a formatted Excel spreadsheet as *.csv and then try to import it into R, then you have two problems. Commas are not allowed in numbers in R (or they are interpreted as decimal point - depends on your locale setting) so, e.g. `as.numeric("1,000")` will return `NA`, not 1000. You have to get rid of the commas and also convert from factor to numeric.

```
a <- factor(c("10","20","30","40","50"))
as.numeric(a)               # returns the factor codes!!
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
as.numeric(as.character(a)) # returns the factor levels, as numeric
# [1] 10 20 30 40 50

b <- factor(c(10,20,30,40,50))
as.numeric(b)               # returns the factor codes!!
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

c <- factor(c("1,000","2,000","3,000","4,000","5,000"))
as.numeric(c)               # returns the factor codes
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
as.numeric(as.character(c)) # returns NA - commas are NOT allowed in numbers in R
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 
as.numeric(gsub(",","",c,fixed=TRUE))
# [1] 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000
```

In the last line, `gsub(",","",c,fixed=TRUE)` just removes the commas.

**EDIT**
As @CarlWitthoft points out in the comment, if the commas are *decimal separators*, you can import the data using:

```
df <- read.csv("mydata.csv", dec=",")
```

This will avoid a lot of problems later. Given the (already imported) dataset you present in the question, this will fix it:

```
datatest$HOURS.at.sea <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",datatest$HOURS.at.sea,fixed=TRUE))
```

This replaces the `","` with `"."`. Since `gsub(...)` returns a character vector, not a factor, you can use `as.numeric(...)` directly on that. Notice that you still get some `NA`s, because some of the rows have `"#VALUE!"` - looks like an Excel dump.

Comment: That's not strictly correct.  "commas vs. periods"  depends on the your Locale setting.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes. I posted this about an hour before OP added the `dput`, and assumed the reference to commas was to thousands separator. This is a common problem when exporting formatted Excel docs to csv and importing that into R. In OP's case it looks like they have commas as the decimal separator. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but no thanks for criminally misspelling my name :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry. Edited.